# Cannot create sink whose type is HDFS in flume-ng

Tags: hdfs, flume

I have a flume-ng which write logs to HDFS.
I made one agent in a single node.
But it is not running.
There is my configuration.

---

# example2.conf: A single-node Flume configuration

# Name the components on this agent
agent1.sources = source1
agent1.sinks = sink1
agent1.channels = channel1

# Describe/configure source1
agent1.sources.source1.type = avro
agent1.sources.source1.bind = localhost
agent1.sources.source1.port = 41414

# Use a channel which buffers events in memory
agent1.channels.channel1.type = memory
agent1.channels.channel1.capacity = 10000
agent1.channels.channel1.transactionCapacity = 100

# Describe sink1
agent1.sinks.sink1.type = HDFS
agent1.sinks.sink1.hdfs.path = hdfs://dbkorando.kaist.ac.kr:9000/flume

# Bind the source and sink the channel
agent1.sources.source1.channels = channel1
agent1.sinks.sink1.channel = channel1

---

and i command

`flume-ng agent -n agent1 -c conf -C /home/hyahn/hadoop-0.20.2/hadoop-0.20.2-core.jar -f conf/example2.conf -Dflume.root.logger=INFO,console`

The Result is

---

Info: Including Hadoop libraries found via (/home/hyahn/hadoop-0.20.2/bin/hadoop) for HDFS access
+ exec /usr/java/jdk1.7.0_02/bin/java -Xmx20m -Dflume.root.logger=INFO,console -cp '/etc/flume-ng/conf:/usr/lib/flume-ng/lib/*:/home/hyahn/hadoop-0.20.2/hadoop-0.20.2-core.jar' -Djava.library.path=:/home/hyahn/hadoop-0.20.2/bin/../lib/native/Linux-amd64-64 org.apache.flume.node.Application -n agent1 -f conf/example2.conf
2012-11-27 15:33:17,250 (main) [INFO - org.apache.flume.lifecycle.LifecycleSupervisor.start(LifecycleSupervisor.java:67)] Starting lifecycle supervisor 1
2012-11-27 15:33:17,253 (main) [INFO - org.apache.flume.node.FlumeNode.start(FlumeNode.java:54)] Flume node starting - agent1
2012-11-27 15:33:17,257 (lifecycleSupervisor-1-1) [INFO - org.apache.flume.conf.file.AbstractFileConfigurationProvider.start(AbstractFileConfigurationProvider.java:67)] Configuration provider starting
2012-11-27 15:33:17,257 (lifecycleSupervisor-1-0) [INFO - org.apache.flume.node.nodemanager.DefaultLogicalNodeManager.start(DefaultLogicalNodeManager.java:203)] Node manager starting
2012-11-27 15:33:17,258 (lifecycleSupervisor-1-0) [INFO - org.apache.flume.lifecycle.LifecycleSupervisor.start(LifecycleSupervisor.java:67)] Starting lifecycle supervisor 9
2012-11-27 15:33:17,258 (conf-file-poller-0) [INFO - org.apache.flume.conf.file.AbstractFileConfigurationProvider$FileWatcherRunnable.run(AbstractFileConfigurationProvider.java:195)] Reloading configuration file:conf/example2.conf
2012-11-27 15:33:17,266 (conf-file-poller-0) [INFO - org.apache.flume.conf.FlumeConfiguration$AgentConfiguration.addProperty(FlumeConfiguration.java:988)] Processing:sink1
2012-11-27 15:33:17,266 (conf-file-poller-0) [INFO - org.apache.flume.conf.FlumeConfiguration$AgentConfiguration.addProperty(FlumeConfiguration.java:988)] Processing:sink1
2012-11-27 15:33:17,267 (conf-file-poller-0) [INFO - org.apache.flume.conf.FlumeConfiguration$AgentConfiguration.addProperty(FlumeConfiguration.java:988)] Processing:sink1
2012-11-27 15:33:17,268 (conf-file-poller-0) [INFO - org.apache.flume.conf.FlumeConfiguration$AgentConfiguration.addProperty(FlumeConfiguration.java:902)] Added sinks: sink1 Agent: agent1
2012-11-27 15:33:17,290 (conf-file-poller-0) [INFO - org.apache.flume.conf.FlumeConfiguration.validateConfiguration(FlumeConfiguration.java:122)] Post-validation flume configuration contains configuration for agents: [agent1]
2012-11-27 15:33:17,290 (conf-file-poller-0) [INFO - org.apache.flume.conf.properties.PropertiesFileConfigurationProvider.loadChannels(PropertiesFileConfigurationProvider.java:249)] Creating channels
2012-11-27 15:33:17,354 (conf-file-poller-0) [INFO - org.apache.flume.instrumentation.MonitoredCounterGroup.(MonitoredCounterGroup.java:68)] Monitoried counter group for type: CHANNEL, name: channel1, registered successfully.
2012-11-27 15:33:17,355 (conf-file-poller-0) [INFO - org.apache.flume.conf.properties.PropertiesFileConfigurationProvider.loadChannels(PropertiesFileConfigurationProvider.java:273)] created channel channel1
2012-11-27 15:33:17,368 (conf-file-poller-0) [INFO - org.apache.flume.instrumentation.MonitoredCounterGroup.(MonitoredCounterGroup.java:68)] Monitoried counter group for type: SOURCE, name: source1, registered successfully.
2012-11-27 15:33:17,378 (conf-file-poller-0) [INFO - org.apache.flume.sink.DefaultSinkFactory.create(DefaultSinkFactory.java:70)] Creating instance of sink: sink1, type: HDFS

---

As above, the problem that flume-ng stop at the sink generating part has occurred.
What is the problem?

Comment: What are you using the `-C` argument for?

Answer (score 1):

you need to open another window and send an avro command at port `41414` as:

```
bin/flume-ng avro-client --conf conf -H localhost -p 41414 -F /home/hadoop1/aaa.txt -Dflume.root.logger=DEBUG,console
```

here i have a file named `aaa.txt` at `/home/hadoop1/` directory

your flume will read this file and send to hdfs.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. however, it is not solution for my problem. Sink  of our Flume is not generated.